# jQuery rebind function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have a div that animates the currently active image out of the view and instead animates in another image. There are several of these divs, and each one should have the same basic functionality but linked to different images. The problem I'm having is that you can click many of the divs before the animation is complete, which fires the other animations at the same time. My goal is to only be able to fire one animation at a time, and when the animation finishes you're able to fire the next animation. I've tried using unbind which works OK but then I'd have to rebind it later and I don't know how to do this. I'm really a jQuery noob so I would greatly apreciate an answer. Thanks!

My code:

```
$('.div1').click(function clickevent() {
    $('.img2, .img3').animate({
        opacity: 0.1,
        left: 600
    }, 1000, function() {
        $('.img1').animate({
            opacity: 1,
            left: 0
        }, 500, function() {
            $('.div2, .div3').bind('click', clickevent); /* Here I want to rebind the function */
        });
    });
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $('.div2, div3').removeClass("active");
    $('div2, .div3').unbind('click', clickevent);
});
```

I have two other codeblocks for .div2 and .div3 which look the same but with different classes in different places. Is there any way to make the images finish their animation before being able to animate again? Thanks.

Comment: yep use `.queue();` just after `.animate()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need:

```
var canAnimate = true;
$('.div1').click(function clickevent() {
    // these 4 lines have to be in all code blocks (ie. for .div2 and .div3)
    if (! canAnimate) {
        return;
    }
    canAnimate = false;

    $('.img2, .img3').animate({
        opacity: 0.1,
        left: 600
    }, 1000, function() {
        $('.img1').animate({
            opacity: 1,
            left: 0
        }, 500, function() {
            canAnimate = true; // this should also be included for .div2 and .div3 code blocks
        });
    });
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $('.div2, div3').removeClass("active");
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your code, I'm like I said a complete noob with jQuery, so if you could elaborate on your answer I'd be very gratefull. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with jQuery...Anyway I've updated my code to include everything.

Comment: I suppose I'm a bit of an overall noob then ;). Your solution seems to work the first time the div is cliked, not later though. Could this be because of the if statement.? How can I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you also added the `canAnimate = true;` in the other code blocks? It should work that way. I've updated my code with a comment.

Comment: And you did remove the unbinding code, right? If you did, I can't really see the issue. Could you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ example and post it?

Comment: EDIT: for some reason the old JsFiddle code appears to me, with only one block of code and the wrong css. Do I have to save it somewhere tro be able to link to my jsfiddle?  http://jsfiddle.net/vvFfa/ as you can see the images overlap each other and doesn't allow for finished animations. Thanks

Comment: After you make changes click on update on the top bar, and you'll get a new version. Paste the link again here when you're done.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vvFfa/1/ as you can see the images overlap each other and doesn't allow for finished animations. Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vvFfa/2/ - Here I've simplified your code to only use one code block for all divs and images. It also works correctly, given the initial question. The problem with images overlapping is something entirely different, it's a css issue. You'll need to post a different question for that, as this one has been answered from my point of view.

Comment: Thank you but your system doesn't work seeing how everything turns transparent if I click on the same object twice...Or am I mistaken?

Comment: You're right, sorry about that, didn't notice it. It was an easy fix though, you can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/vvFfa/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot but I'm still having a problem with the function being able to fire before the other animation is completed...

Comment: What do you mean by that? If I click on div1 then clicks on the other divs won't work until the animation is finished.

Comment: Sure they will, you can have many visible animations at a time. The goal is that only one should be able to animate at a time. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Indeed, if you clicked very fast between them it happended. This was a bit more weird to fix, but it's because animate triggers once for each matched element. Here's the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/vvFfa/4/

Comment: Thanks a lot for putting so much time and effort into helping me! One last question: How would I achive the same effect but in the block format like it was in my opening question or your first answer? I'd apreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see why you'd want it this way, but I've updated it once more here - http://jsfiddle.net/vvFfa/5/

Comment: It's because I might have to useother class names for the images or maybe nth-child selectors later on.The problem I'm now having is that the animation to bring in the second image after the first one is out starts to early and gets in before the first one even started to get out. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks again!

Comment: It's very strange because your jsfiddle works without problems and I'm using your exact code...Strange.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to describe, I've tried clicking and everything is behaving normally for me. Anyway, this is getting too long, I'll move it to chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4645/discussion-between-draevor-and-user1023552)

Answer (score 1):

I think queue() will append the animations but not stop them, so if you click 10 times on the images, the click handler will animate it 10 times but one after another. I guess you want only animate the images when no image is currenty animated so you can use:

```
$('.div1').click(function clickevent() {
    // When no image is currently animated then perform the animation
    if($j('.img1, .img2, .img3').is(':animated') == false)
    {
        $('.img2, .img3').animate({
            opacity: 0.1,
            left: 600
        }, 1000, function() {
            $('.img1').animate({
                opacity: 1,
                left: 0
            }, 500);
        });
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $('.div2, div3').removeClass("active");
   } else {
        // There is currently an animation runnig, do nothing
   }
});
```

See this for more information: http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/

You should also get some information about caching of selection results.

Comment: I'm terrible sorry for my lack of understanding about jQuery but could you please tell me where I should put your code snippet. Thanks for taking time to answer my question, I apreciate it.